# Google Maps Zooming Level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to make Google Maps zoom to a certain level based on what is being searched?
For instance, if I am searching for a street, then when I search for the street, google maps would zoom to the street level.

When I am searching for a city, the google maps will zoom to the city level, etc ...

Thanks

Comment: What does "zoom to the street level" or "zoom to the city level" mean? Zoom levels are defined by integers, not by phrases.

Answer (score 1):

try this below links, here you will have some different maps level information.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#MapTypes

and

[How to set google map custom zoom level dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424684/how-to-set-google-map-custom-zoom-level-dynamically?rq=1)

[Google Maps v3 - limit viewable area and zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level)

it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I solved this issue using the following line of code:

```
map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
```

I use the above line of code after I get a Status "OK" from geocoding web service. It works fine.

Comment: What Class is object map? MapView doesn't have fitBounds method.  Same question for object results[0]. Is it meant to be Address as result of geoCoder.getFromLocationName ? But again no geometry member...

Comment: Seems like you guys are in JavaScript, and I am in Android waters. Sorry about that... I have the same problem in Android. :-S